# How can I access the class method and instance method in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

By searching some blog and article I found that every class in Ruby is itself an instance of `Class`. What is the difference between class methods and instance methods and did ruby allow to create object of object?

I try to do something like this but still not able to understand

```
str = Class.new(String)
=> #<Class:0xb5be1418>

my_str = str.new()
=> ""

my_str = str.new("hello")
=> "hello"

my_str.class
=> #<Class:0xb5be1418>

str.class
=> Class
```

NOW FULLY CONFUSED so tell me about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Dog
 # Returns the number of dog objects created using this class
 def self.count
 end

 # Returns name of the dog object
 def name
 end
end
```

From the above example, the generic method( which is related to all dog objects ) is called the `class method`.

Method that is related to a particular dog( dog object ) is called `instance method`.

According to ruby object models, `Dog` is a `constant` that points to an instance of class `Class`. Whenever a class method is added to Dog, a new class called `Metaclass` will be added in the class hierarchy to keep the class methods.

Answer (score 4):

In the first sentence you create anonymous class with superclass of `String`:

```
my_str.class.superclass # => String
```

But this is not the essence of your actual question :)

Instance is an object of some class: `String.new() # creates instance of class String`. Instances have classes `(String.new()).class #=> String`. All classes are actually instances of a class `Class`: `String.class # => Class`. Instances of `Class` class also have `superclass` - class that they inherit from.

*Instance method* is a method that you can call on instance of an object.

```
"st ri ng".split # split is an instance method of String class
```

*Class method* in Ruby is a common term for *instance methods* of an object of `Class` class (any class).

```
String.try_convert("abc") # try_convert is a class method of String class.
```

You can read more about instance and class methods in [this article](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/).

Comment: To be completely nit-pickety, class methods are singleton methods of instances of Class

Comment: @FrederickCheung, +1, but I believe this knowledge is not requred for the Ruby beginner to understand difference between Class and Instance methods ;)